# topology of hyperspace

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ a continuous map.
Fix $r>0$, consider all the closed ball of radius $r$, which is denoted by $X_r:=\{B(x,r)|x\in X\}$.
$2^X$ is the hyperspace of $X$, i.e. all the non-empty closed subsets of$X$. Since $X$ is compact, so is $2^X$. Define $f_r:X_r\rightarrow X_r$ by $f_r(B(x,r))=B(f(x),r)$.

**Question 1:**

> Is $X_r$ compact in $2^X$?

**Question 2:**

> Is $f_r$ continuous?

Thank you very much!

Comment: First, you need a topology on $2^X$. How is it defined? Next, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I suppose $2^X$ has the Hausdorff metric topology (or equivalently the Vietoris topology, as $X$ is compact)?